# How can i get a placeholder name with provided url value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For e.g i have a route defined in a routeConfig file

url: "/article/relatedarticles/articleID/{articleID}/{pageNo}"

and i have end url **/article/relatedarticles/articleID/5555/20**

Now what i want is a function that will return to me a placeholder value with its provided parameters like "articleID=5555 and pageNo=20"

**Note that the end url  is saved in DB not directly hitted by the Client**

Comment: you can get these two int value by implementing
YourAction(int articleID, int  pageNo) in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options you have:

1. Fetch the parameters by name from a FormCollection
2. Let MVC model binder map the parameters to properties of a ViewModel or some sort of POCO class
3. Fetch the raw query string / http request and parse it yourself. That will be in the HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString

Sounds like you want the latter.